# Step down transformer vs Electronic voltage regulator for appliances between 220v to 110v

Tags: voltage-regulator, transformer, mains, step-down

I recently purchased an [Instant Pot 6 Quart](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FLYWNYQ) with [specs](https://instantpot.com/portfolio-item/duo/#specifications)(Electric Pressure Cooker) from the US(outlet supply 110v) and would like to send it to a country that has outlet supply of 220v. The cooker is rated at 1000W to only run at 110v. This means that the usage of a step down transformer is a must.

I am looking at something like this. The 5000 in the image means it can take upto 5KW.

[image]

However, I came across these  electronic(SCR) voltage regulators that can do a step down function also. Pictured below is one such device
[image]
[image]

My question is the following: Do both these appliances convert 220v to 110v in the same fashion as far the usage is concerned(Off course the mechanism to achieve is different)? If yes, would it be ok to use any of the two for the pressure cooker? If not, why not?

Comment: Have you checked what those converters cost and what a pressure cooker costs in your destination country? I very much suspect that this is false economy, especially if you add shipping costs.

Comment: The pressure cooker is not available online in that country. It is available in Amazon UK for 220v  but then again, there is no way to ship it from Amazon UK to destination

Comment: Please provide a link to the cooker.

Comment: @BruceAbbott https://www.amazon.com/Instant-Pot-Multi-Use-Programmable-Pressure/dp/B00FLYWNYQ/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=2YNJE6UDJMJLG&keywords=instant+pot&qid=1576037541&sprefix=instan%2Caps%2C195&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzMlc4RTBPVzA3N0dOJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjEyNjM3MkNFRTZOQ0NDNDdMSyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMDYwNTYyMzBEUVRUU1NHNllQViZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=

Comment: This is a lot of work for a rice cooker. And who wants that huge box in their kitchen beside it???

Comment: @C.K. this is not a rice cooker. Its one of the best kitchen appliances in the last few years. Has 7 built in cooking techniques and makes the entire process of cooking EXTREMELY easy. Try it and your opinion might change :)

Comment: @auny I might not agree with that, but whatever floats your boat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cooker is described as:-

> America’s most loved multi cooker, built with the latest 3rd
>   generation technology, **the microprocessor** monitors pressure,
>   temperature, keeps time, and **adjusts heating intensity** and duration to
>   achieve desired results every time.

It may use [phase control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-fired_controller) (like a light dimmer) to control cooking power. This would be done with an [SCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_controlled_rectifier) or [TRIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC), which delays switching power to the heater until part way through each mains cycle. Alternatively it might use 'zero-crossing' switching, which lets through a proportion of full mains cycles to vary the average power.

The THYEISTORELETEONINICVOLTACETTCUATOR probably also uses phase control to produce the heating effect of a lower voltage (another name for SCR is [Thyristor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyristor)). This works well with purely resistive loads such as a heater or incandescent lamp, but not with devices which are expecting a full sine wave input - such as your cooker.

The step down transformer reduces voltage without changing the waveform, so it should work with most devices. The only potential problem is that countries with 220V mains often run at 50Hz rather than 60Hz. Hopefully the controller in your cooker is smart enough to adjust itself to the different mains frequency. Symptoms of not doing so may include 20% slower timing (eg. cooking for 12 minutes when set to 10 minutes) and incorrect power levels if using phase control.